# Reading from FTP socket stream trigger an infinite loop

Tags: php, sockets, ftp

I'm currently developing a [PHP library](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-bridge) that allows implementing FTP functions at a low level following the [RFC959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) standards, so you can use it for example to create adjusted FTP functions especially for your needs, or you can develop an entire FTP client library without the need for the FTP extension.

I've been banging my head against a wall with a problem for hours, I have a method [`FtpCommandStream::receive()`](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-bridge/blob/f836de4594fcfd793bbfea57449f4d970ba28902/src/Stream/FtpCommandStream.php#L68) which can be used to receive the FTP reply string representation after sending an FTP command with [`FtpCommandStream::send()`](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-bridge/blob/f836de4594fcfd793bbfea57449f4d970ba28902/src/Stream/FtpCommandStream.php#L60) method, the problem is if I call the `receive` method without sending any command or the control stream was empty then an infinite loop will be trigged.

I'm not going to call this method without sending any command internally, A library user may call the `receive` method twice or before sending any command, this will trigger an infinite loop and cause other side effects.

The `receive()` method code:

```php
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function receive()
{
    $response = '';
    
    // Check first if the command stream is empty or not!!

    while (true) {
        $line     = fgets($this->stream);
        $response .= $line;

        /**
         * To distinguish the end of an FTP reply, the RFC959 indicates that the last line of
         * a the reply must be on a special format, it must be begin with 3 digits followed
         * by a space.
         *
         * @link https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959#section-4
         */
        if (preg_match('/\d{3}+ /', $line) !== 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $this->log($response);

    return $response;
}
```

To solve the problem we have to check if the command stream is empty before trying to read from it with `fgets` or `fread` functions, I've tried to use the `foef` but doesn't work (works only with the data stream see [here](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-bridge/blob/f836de4594fcfd793bbfea57449f4d970ba28902/src/Stream/FtpDataStream.php#L59)), I really am struggling to find a solution so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not going to call this method without sending any command internally, A library user may call the `receive` method twice or before sending any command, this will trigger an infinite loop and cause other side effects.

That's the problem of the library user, not yours. Clearly document under what circumstances can the function be called. There's no way for you to find out if the server is not going to send any response or if the response just didn't not arrive yet.